# Web Audio API Processor result

Tags: web, audio, return-value, web-audio-api, processor

I am doing some audio processing with JS, using [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)
So I've created a custom [Audio Worklet Processor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor) in which I am processing some audio.

Here is a small example.

```
class MyProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  process (inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    const someProcessedNumber = cppApiProcessor.process(inputs,outputs,parameters);
    return true; // to keep the processor alive
  }
}
```

You see variable `someProcessedNumber` comes from a `cppApi` and I don't know how to let the outer JS world know about that, as the `Processor` returns `boolean` (whether keep the node alive or not), and I cannot touch the data in `outputs`. ( I don't wanna change the outcoming audio, just process and give a number)
How can I do that? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `port` of an `AudioWorkletProcessor` to send data back to the main thread (or any other thread).

```
this.port.postMessage(someProcessedNumber);
```

Every `AudioWorkletNode` has a `port` as well which can be used to receive the message.

Using the `MessagePort` will generate some garbage on the audio thread which makes the garbage collection run from time to time. It's also not the most performant way to transfer data.

If that's an issue you can use a `SharedArrayBuffer` instead which the `AudioWorkletProcessor` uses to write the data and the `AudioWorkletNode` uses to read the data.

[ringbuf.js](https://github.com/padenot/ringbuf.js) is a library which aims to make this process as easy as possible.

Comment: I actually used `port` to transfer data from outter JS world to the `Pocessor` but I did not know that it works the other way too, thanks very much)